# Unable to launch virtualbox GUI via terminal on newly created user account

Tags: virtualbox

```
$ virtualbox
```

Returns the error below when trying to launch virtualbox GUI on secondary account. Can someone please help me resolve this? The user has already been added to the sudo, vboxusers and libvirtd group.

```
No protocol specified
Qt FATAL: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted (core dumped)
```